# Sending a jQuery variable to Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to get the variable "response.data.uri" from my jQuery to a rails controller, but it isn't working. I can get to the rails controller but the variable isnt there.

**jQuery:**

```
function responseCallbackHandler(response) {
   switch (response.status) {
     case 201:
         $.ajax({ url: '#{addbank_bankaccts_path}',
         type: 'POST',
         beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', '#{form_authenticity_token}')},
         dataType: "json",
         data: 'account_uri=' + response.data.uri
         success: function(response) {
           // successfully executed the controller method
           }
         });
         break;
     }
 }
```

**routes.rb:**

```
post "/bankaccts/new" => 'bankaccts#addbank'
```

**controller:**

```
class BankacctsController < ApplicationController

  def addbank
      @uri = (params['customer_uri'])
      @id = (params['id'])
      @auri = (params['account_uri'])
      # all equal nil ^
      redirect_to root_url
  end
```

Comment: I don't see you using `params['account_uri']`, have you tried that?

Comment: no params['account_uri'] is nil

Comment: Check your `params` hash in your controller to make sure data is coming through and also check if `response.data.uri` has your expected value in the browser console.

Comment: response.data.uri indeed has the value I want in the js let me check the params

Comment: yeah nothing in params when i get to the controller

Comment: How about posting the jqery as it appears in the browser?  If response.data.uri has the correct values in the browser, and nothing shows up in params on the server, then the request isn't being sent--which you should also be able to check in the browser's console.  The browser console can show you all the requests that were sent and all responses that were received--including all the data contained in the request or response.

Comment: in the jQuery if i do console.log it shows the value fine but when i get to the controller it doenst

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I know: In ruby, single quotes do not perform variable interpolation.  So if you posted the jquery as it appears in the browser, the url for you ajax request would be:

```
'#{addbank_bankaccts_path}'
```

...which is gibberish--a browser does not understand ruby or rails.  Url's in a browser must look like:

```
http://mysite.com/js/myjs.js
js/myjs.js
```

If your jquery is in a file whose name ends with .erb, then before sending the file to the browser rails will execute any ruby code in the file, but single quotes in ruby do not perform variable interpolation.  Here is an example of that:

```
name = 'Dave'
str = '#{name} says hello.'
puts str

--output:--
#{name} says hello
```

But with double quotes:

```
name = 'Dave'
str = "#{name} says hello."
puts str

--output:--
Dave says hello.
```

I don't know if you are coming from a python background or not, where all quotes are equivalent; but in a lot of languages, including ruby, single and double quotes are not equivalent.

Your form_authenticity_token has the same problem:

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', '#{form_authenticity_token}')},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try -

data: {account_uri: response.data.uri, 'customer_uri': SOME_VALUE, 'id': SOME_VALUE}